# USB display drivers on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, display, 17.04

I have a USB monitor adapter (UV Plus 39) https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=100-U3-UV39-KR
It worked great with the displaylink drivers http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu when I was running ubuntu 16.10 and ever since I updated to 17.04 my monitor has either shown a black screen, glitchy looking colors or my background, but it isn't responsive. Displaylink has released an update since then for their drivers but that hasn't helped. I've reinstalled my drivers and tried different monitors and displays configurations with no luck.

The monitor does show up in my display settings, and if I move the mouse to the edge of the screen it moves as if there's a monitor there, I can put windows on that monitor and so on, but I can't see it.

I'm happy to provide any additional info needed.

Comment: This seems to be related to the suggested fixes here: http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades